# Angular Routing and placing router outlets

Tags: angular, routes, router-outlet

How to place the router outlet for child routes, without affecting the main router outlet

My parents components are displayed in the main router outlet. I have a navigation in a component that navigation contains child routes , where it's child components plug into this parent component. But when i navigate to another parent component the links defined in that parent component doesn't work. This is the issue i have, want to solve it.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        component: HomeComponent,
        // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
        path: ""
      },
      {
        component: RegisterComponent,
        path: "Register"
      },
      {
        component: ProductsComponent,
        path: "Products"
      },
      {
        component:  ReceprionistProductsEditComponent,
        path:"Receptionistproductedit"
      },
      {
        component: ReceptionistProductsComponent,
        path: "Receptionist",
        children: [
          {
            component: MenSuitsFormComponent,
            path: "suitform/:title"
          },
          {
            path: "tightsform/:title",
            component: TightsFormComponent
          },
          {
            component: AccessoriesFormComponent,
            path: "accessoriesform/:title"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path:'aaa',
        component:TightsFormComponent,
        outlet:"addProducts"
      }

    ])
```

In the "ReceptionistProductComponent"

```
<app-receptionist-navigation></app-receptionist-navigation>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="mt-5">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="['/Receptionist/suitform',items[1]]">Shirts </a> </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="['/Receptionist/tightsform',items[2]]">Trousers</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="['/Receptionist/tightsform',items[3]]">Shorts</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="['/Receptionist/suitform',items[4]]">Sarees</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="['/Receptionist/accessoriesform','Accessories']">Accessories</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { addProduts: ['/Receptionist/suitform',items[1]] }}]">Example</a></li>
    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary:['Receptionist'],addProducts: ['aaa'] }}]">Contact</a>
    <a routerLink="/aaa">Contact1</a>
  </ol>
</nav>
<router-outlet>/*This is a sub router outlet not the main one. Above child links are routed here*/</router-outlet>
```

When i try to move to a different parent component the links in that parent component doesn't work.

Comment: Effectively any "parent" route with a `children` property needs to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Is that the case in your application currently?

Comment: If i remove the mentioned router outlet then the components relates to the child routes won't be displayed.

Comment: In your case, you must have one more router-outlet inside your child component to host your required component.